# SweetAlert2 not working and stopped in IE11

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_index.css">
        <script src="js/testjs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    ...

    <body>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" required>
            <button name="button" onclick="swal('Hi!')">Search1</button>
            <button name="button2" onclick="alert('hi2')">Search2</button>
        </div>

    ...
```

this is my code.

Search2 button works well, but Search1 button doesn't.
When I click this button, page has a lack and not work in IE11.
but in chrome it has no problem... I can't figure out why it does...
plz help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sweetalert2 uses [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but promises are not implemented by IE11. You have to include a polyfill ([it's written in the docs](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2#usage)). If you don't include the polyfill, you will have an error in the developer console logs (F12) `"Promise" is undefined`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.26.12/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include a polyfill for ES6 Promises -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="search">
              <input type="text" id="search" name="search" required>
              <button name="button" onclick="swal('Hi!')">Search1</button>
              <button name="button2" onclick="alert('hi2')">Search2</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! perfect!